# what does this mean x86 assembly code mean?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have come upon x86 assembly code I don't understand and can't find anything about it. The bit of code i don't understand is parentheses around register ecx: `movb (%ecx),%al`. What does this code mean? I am familiar with registers and instructions, but have never come upon this.

I was trying to find something about it in videos and guides, but did not find anything.

## Looks something like this in context

```
pushl %ebp 
movl %esp,%ebp 
movl 8(%ebp),%ecx 
...
movb (%ecx),%al  #<-- the code i am wondering about
```

Comment: it's referring to the memory address held in the register, like dereference.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `(%reg)` is the AT&T assembler syntax for dereferencing the content of a register as an address. It's equivalent to the Intel syntax `[reg]`.

What you have there is the value in the partial register `%al` being written into the byte pointed to by the address in `%ecx`.